# When does wcf msmq service goes to fault state

Tags: wcf

I have created a wcf service with NetMsmq binding. And the operations are one way.

I wanted to handle the fault exception. However i found that the channel is not going to fault even after the exception is raised at the server side.
Can anybody tell me in what cases the wcf service will goes to fault state(provided while using NetMsmqBinding).